# Xpath for node without text but child has text

Tags: selenium, xpath

I am having an issue trying to find a node that doesnot have text but their child has an specific text.

Here is an example of the html code:

```
<strong>
  This is not 
<span>the one</span>
</strong>
<strong>
<span>the one</span>
</strong>
```

So I need to find the second strong.. but the xpath that I am using is this one:

```
//strong/span[text()='the one']
```

This brings me the two elements ... but I need the second one.

I tried something like this:

```
//strong[not(text())]/span[text()='the one']
```

but it didn't work..

Any idea how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
//strong[not(normalize-space(text()))]/span[text()='the one']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Index to identify the position. But note that here indices start from 1.

```
(//strong/span[text()='the one'])[2]
```